# How to get config_currency by store_id in admin>controller>catalog>product.php

Tags: php, opencart, config, currency

I have multi store Opencart 3.0.3.2. Default store using USD as default currency and second store using GBP as default currecy.

I can get default store's default currency in admin>controller>catalog>product.php

`$this->config->get('config_currency')`

How can I get default currency of second store?

Thanks in advance!